# Custom software in AWS Lambda Environment

Tags: java, python, aws-lambda

I want to run a Python wrapper in AWS Lambda. The Python wrapper needs to call an external program through command line. I use Python subprocess package to call the external program. The program called is `embulk` - a java application used for bulk transfer. (http://www.embulk.org/docs/)

On my local Mac, I have `embulk` installed and the Python wrapper successfully calls `embulk` to move Amazon S3 data to our cloud data warehouse (on TreasureData). For this Python wrapper to work on Lambda, I somehow need to get `embulk` installed in the AWS Lambda Environment. Is it possible to do that? Or do I need to buy an EC2 instance to get this working?

Comment: Does `embulk` have any requirements, like an installed Java environment? Then this probably won't work on a *Python lambda*. You can typically run any executable which can run on a plain Linux distribution without additional dependencies. There are separate Lambda environments for Java…

Comment: The AMI environment has got standard Java installed. However, it does not have embulk installed.

Comment: Soooo… https://stackoverflow.com/q/45101513/476

Answer (score 0):

To get Java running in a Python Lambda environment will require you to package the whole JDK with your Lambda code. You'll have to make sure it matches exactly to AWS' x86 Linux distro they use.

The better approach is to implement your code entirely in Java. Create your own Java Lambda class that invokes Embulk's existing main class.

If you're not comfortable with Java, you could write a small amount of Java to implement the Lambda Handler, which then invokes a Jython script (Python-in-Java), which then invokes the main method of Embulk.

As a Python developer, you ought to find Java relatively easy to understand if you're already using Object Oriented Python.